# Duplicate pages. Blocking an address without variables PHP

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to achieve this effect:

https://example.home/blog.php --- redirecting --> 404,

https://example.home/blog.php?id=... --- redirecting --> blog.php?id= (here random ID, from 1 to 1000 - for example)

The website is displayed at: /blog.php?id=57,

but also at this address: /blog.php?id=test-post

How do you block indexing of web addresses that contain ID?

How to get a website address to look like this: http://example.home/blog/test-post

Answer (score 0):

There is a full guide to mod_rewrite here that looks pretty good. You have to scroll down a bit to get to url as parameters.

https://www.branded3.com/blog/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/

If you don't want to mess too much with mod_rewrite and already have everything directed through a single public index.php (which is a good idea anyway). Then you can do something a little more dirty like this.

```
/**
 * Get the given variable from $_REQUEST or from the url
 * @param string $variableName
 * @param mixed $default
 * @return mixed|null
 */
function getParam($variableName, $default = null) {

    // Was the variable actually part of the request
    if(array_key_exists($variableName, $_REQUEST))
        return $_REQUEST[$variableName];

    // Was the variable part of the url
    $urlParts = explode('/', preg_replace('/\?.+/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    $position = array_search($variableName, $urlParts);
    if($position !== false && array_key_exists($position+1, $urlParts))
        return $urlParts[$position+1];

    return $default;
}
```

Note that this checks for any _GET, _POST or _HEADER parameter with the same name first. Then it checks each part of the url for a given key, and returns the following part. So you can do something like:

```
// On http://example.com/news/18964
getParam('news');
// returns 18964
```